# Error al validar una contraseña usando expresiones regulares

Tags: java, regex, map

Tengo en un programa dos métodos en clases separadas de la main, en uno valido un nombre de usuario introducido en el main, y en el otro una contraseña.
Mi problema es que cuando introduzco estas en un mapa, la contraseña aparece siempre como "null", así que sospecho que viene a ser un error de utilización de expresiones regulares.

Main:

```
public class MenuTreeMap {
        public static String menu(){
        System.out.println("Elija lo que quiera hacer a continuación");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("1.-Alta de usuario.");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        return null;
        }
        static String mUsu;
        static String mPass;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean flag = false;
        boolean mFlag = false;

        menu();
        while (mFlag==false){
        TreeMap <String, String> t = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner menu = new Scanner(System.in);
        String mENU=menu.nextLine();
        switch(mENU)
        {

            case "1":


        //Validar e introducir Usuario
        //--------------------------------------
        System.out.println("Introduzca un nombre de usuario, de 8 a 20 caracteres");
        while(!flag){
        mUsu=input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");
        ValidarUsuario valUsu= new ValidarUsuario();


        if( valUsu.valUsu()==true ){
        System.out.println("Usuario valido, nombre de usuario " + mUsu);
        flag=true;
        }else{
            System.out.println("El usuario no era válido");
        }
        }

        //--------------------------------------
        //Validar e introducir contraseña
                System.out.println("Introduzca una contraseña, de 8 a 20. Debe incluir un símbolo especial.");
        while(!flag){
        mUsu=input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");
        ValidarContrasena valPass= new ValidarContrasena();


        if( valPass.valPass()==true ){
        System.out.println("Contraseña válida");
        flag=true;
        }else{
             System.out.println("El Contraseña no válida");
        }
        }

        //---------------------------------------
        t.put("mUsu", "mPass");
        break;

        }
    }
    }
```

Clase ValidarUsuario:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 *
 * @author julia
 */
public class ValidarUsuario {
     //Validar un usuario

    public static boolean valUsu(){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Pattern p=Pattern.compile("[\\w]+");

        boolean comp=true;


        System.out.println("Validando... ... ... ...");
        System.out.println("");
        Matcher m=p.matcher(Tarea051GestionarCredenciales.mUsu);

        try{
            if( m.matches() && Tarea051GestionarCredenciales.mUsu.length()>=8 && Tarea051GestionarCredenciales.mUsu.length()<=20){



                    comp=true;
                }else{
                comp=false;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Introduzca un usuario válido");
        }


        return comp;

}
}
```

Clase ValidarContraseña

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 *
 * @author julia
 */
public class ValidarContrasena {
    public static boolean valPass(){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Pattern p=Pattern.compile("[\\w!@#$]{8,20}");

        boolean comp=true;


        System.out.println("Validando... ... ... ...");
        System.out.println("");
        Matcher m=p.matcher(Tarea051GestionarCredenciales.mPass);

        try{
            if( m.matches() && Tarea051GestionarCredenciales.mPass.length()>=8 && Tarea051GestionarCredenciales.mPass.length()<=20){



                    comp=true;
                }else{
                comp=false;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Introduzca un usuario válido");
        }


        return comp;

}
}
```

Con esa expresión regular en la contraseña, lo que quiero es que la contraseña sea de entre 8 y 20 caracteres, y tenga que incluir un caracter especial.
Como podéis observar, tanto ValidarUsuario como ValidarContrasena están construidas de la misma manera.
Entre las opciones que he intentado, ha sido decirle en la expresión regular que longitud debe tener.
También añadir que los mensajes de la clase principal para comprobar que se ha introducido una contraseña adecuada no se imprimen, imagino que porque la contraseña no es adecuada, pero tampoco salta el mensaje de que no lo sea.
Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. No entiendo dónde tienes el problema, hablas de que hay un null pero tus métodos devuelve boolean. Te aconsejo que reduzcas el ámbito de la pregunta; primero que detectes realmente cuál es el problema (¿expresión regular?¿introduces los datos de forma incorrecta?) y luego hagas un mini-programa que solo compruebe eso (por ejemplo, que compruebe si la expresión regular funciona usando como prueba una cadena que le pasas por código.

Comment: Y, en general, es buena práctica separar el código en métodos o clases con funciones específicas; en este caso solo el validar la contraseña podría ser su propia clase (o método) y así lo puedes probar de forma independente al código de leer e imprimir datos.

Comment: Cuidado con las variables estáticas. Las variables estáticas no pertenecen a los objetos creados por una clase, sino que son comunes a la clase. Si creas una variable estática "nombre" en una clase persona, cuando tengas 3 objetos persona, los 3 tendrán el mismo nombre. Y si cambias el nombre a 1, lo cambias a los 3. (y para cambiarlo no lo haces por objeto.propiedad sino por clase.propiedad.) Así que lo dicho, cuidado con las variables estáticas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es de control de lfujo... y si... hay detalles en la expresión regular pero eso no impide correrlo.

Hay un principio de diseño agrupado en SOLID llamado Single Responsability, que quiere decir que no intentes hacer encargarte de hacer varias cosas a la vez, sino que te enfoques, haciéndote responsable solo de una de ellas.

En este caso el problema es que tu variable flag la estás usando para controlar tanto la validación de tu usuario como de tu password, y pasando la validación de tu usuario se queda en verdadero, así que nunca entra a la validadción de tu password, y como tu bandera para el menu nunca se apaga se queda esperando infinitamente.

Una corrección rápida sería:

## Menu tree map

```
package com.stackoverflow.es.question356293;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class MenuTreeMap {
    public static void menu() {
        System.out.println("Elija lo que quiera hacer a continuación");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("1.-Alta de usuario.");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    }

    static String mUsu;
    static String mPass;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean userFlag = false;
        boolean passwordFlag = false;
        boolean mFlag = false;

        menu();
        while (!mFlag) {
            TreeMap<String, String> t = new TreeMap<String, String>();
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner menu = new Scanner(System.in);
            String mENU = menu.nextLine();
            switch (mENU) {

                case "1":


                    //Validar e introducir Usuario
                    //--------------------------------------
                    System.out.println("Introduzca un nombre de usuario, de 8 a 20 caracteres");
                    while (!userFlag) {
                        mUsu = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("");


                        if (ValidarUsuario.valUsu()) {
                            System.out.println("Usuario valido, nombre de usuario " + mUsu);
                            userFlag = true;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("El usuario no era válido");
                        }
                    }

                    //--------------------------------------
                    //Validar e introducir contraseña
                    System.out.println("Introduzca una contraseña, de 8 a 20. Debe incluir un símbolo especial.");
                    passwordFlag = false;
                    while (!passwordFlag) {
                        mPass = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("");


                        if (ValidarContrasena.valPass()) {
                            System.out.println("Contraseña válida");
                            passwordFlag = true;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("El Contraseña no válida");
                        }
                    }

                    //---------------------------------------
                    t.put("mUsu", "mPass");
                    //if (passwordFlag && userFlag) {
                    mFlag = true; // hacemos que salga
                    //}
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

## ValidarUsuario

```
package com.stackoverflow.es.question356293;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * @author julia
 */
public class ValidarUsuario {
    //Validar un usuario

    public static boolean valUsu() {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w]+");

        boolean comp = true;


        System.out.println("Validando... ... ... ...");
        System.out.println("");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(MenuTreeMap.mUsu);

        try {
            comp = m.matches() && MenuTreeMap.mUsu.length() >= 8 && MenuTreeMap.mUsu.length() <= 20;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Introduzca un usuario válido");
        }


        return comp;

    }
}
```

## ValidarContrasena

```
package com.stackoverflow.es.question356293;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * @author julia
 */
public class ValidarContrasena {
    public static boolean valPass() {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w!@#$]{8,20}");

        boolean comp = true;


        System.out.println("Validando... ... ... ...");
        System.out.println("");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(MenuTreeMap.mPass);

        try {
            comp = m.matches() && MenuTreeMap.mPass.length() >= 8 && MenuTreeMap.mPass.length() <= 20;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Introduzca una contraseña válida");
        }


        return comp;

    }
}
```

Como verás para desatorarlo hice una variable para manejar aparte la validación del usuario de la validadción de la contraseña.

Una mejora adicional es que no necesitas instanciar tus clases si los métodos que piensas llamar son estáticos, a este tipo de clases se les ocnoce como clases de utilidades. De hecho en tu caso es muy buen diseño, ya que sin darte cuenta hiciste de tus validadores interfaces funcionales.

Aplicando el primer principio de Solid podemos modificar el código de MenuTreeMap a algo más fácil de modificar como esto:

```
package com.stackoverflow.es.question356293;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class MenuTreeMap {
    public static void menu() {
        System.out.println("Elija lo que quiera hacer a continuación");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("1.-Alta de usuario.");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    }

    static String mUsu;
    static String mPass;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean mFlag = false;

        menu();
        while (!mFlag) {
            TreeMap<String, String> t = new TreeMap<String, String>();
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String mENU = input.nextLine();
            switch (mENU) {

                case "1":
                    leerUsuarioValido(input);
                    //--------------------------------------
                    leerPasswordValido(input);
                    //---------------------------------------
                    t.put("mUsu", "mPass");
                    //if (passwordFlag && userFlag) {
                    mFlag = true; // hacemos que salga
                    //}
                    break;

            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validar e introducir contraseña
     */
    private static boolean leerPasswordValido(Scanner input) {
        boolean passwordFlag = false;
        while (!passwordFlag) {
            System.out.println("Introduzca una contraseña, de 8 a 20. Debe incluir un símbolo especial.");
            mPass = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");

            if (ValidarContrasena.valPass()) {
                System.out.println("Contraseña válida");
                passwordFlag = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("El Contraseña no válida");
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Validar e introducir Usuario
     */
    private static boolean leerUsuarioValido(Scanner input) {
        boolean userFlag = false;
        while (!userFlag) {
            System.out.println("Introduzca un nombre de usuario, de 8 a 20 caracteres");
            mUsu = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");


            if (ValidarUsuario.valUsu()) {
                System.out.println("Usuario valido, nombre de usuario " + mUsu);
                userFlag = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("El usuario no era válido");
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```